# Slow query on a two-million-row table

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

In one of my databases, a table `product_listings` has about two million rows and is growing with each month (InnoDB, MySQL 5.5.43).

Details of the table and indices are shown below.

```
mysql> describe table product_listings;
+---------------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                           | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                              | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_id                       | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sku_id                          | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| product_category_id             | int(11) unsigned       | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| title                           | varchar(255)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image_url                       | varchar(512)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page_url                        | varchar(512)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sku_name                        | varchar(100)           | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| listed_qty                      | int(10) unsigned       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| is_mapped                       | tinyint(1) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| status                          | char(1)                | NO   |     | p       |                |
+---------------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> show index from product_listings;
+----------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                | Non_unique | Key_name                                | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| product_listings |          0 | PRIMARY                                |            1 | id                  | A         |     1081897 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| product_listings |          1 | sku_id                                 |            1 | sku_id              | A         |     1081897 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| product_listings |          1 | PL_SkuName_ClientId                    |            1 | sku_name            | A         |     1081897 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| product_listings |          1 | PL_SkuName_ClientId                    |            2 | client_id           | A         |     1081897 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| product_listings |          1 | PL_ProductCategoryId                   |            1 | product_category_id | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| product_listings |          1 | PL_ProductCategoryId                   |            2 | client_id           | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| product_listings |          1 | PL_ProductCategoryId                   |            3 | is_mapped           | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

With the following query, it takes about 10 to 12 seconds.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT  *
    FROM  `product_listings`
    WHERE  `product_category_id` = 303
      AND  `client_id` = 39
      AND  `is_mapped` = '1'
    LIMIT  55000, 100;
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys                     | key                   | key_len | ref               | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ChannelCompanySku | ref  | PL_ProductCategoryId              | PL_ProductCategoryId  | 9       | const,const,const | 557036 |       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------+--------+-------+
```

Not sure what is the root cause for this. Is it my hardware running out of juice? The memory on server is 1GB. How can I find out if the server is maxing out? Doing top says, 41% of memory is still free, can it be trusted?

All other queries are running fine, it's just this one query that is hammering the server down and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Is this a query that you're doing often? It's going to find 55000 matches in the index and then look up the table by `id` 55000 times to get the rest of the fields (because you specified `SELECT *`). It's probably not surprising that it takes a while.

Comment: It doesn't run often. We have to update the calculation for related records belonging to a specific product category, whenever there is a related change. We update records in batches of 100. So, when this update routing kicks in, it just brings down the whole server performance which otherwise is running without hickups.. Average load of system is 0.05, but when this query is gets it for updating all records, it goes to 100%

Comment: Do you need SELECT *? As said by mendosi, this finds 55000 rows out of 557036 (not sure about MySQL Limit impact on queries), then it has to look up rest of the data based on this.

Comment: I can add specific fields to fetch, but that doesn't help much. I am fetching 100 records in a batch with above query and not all 55000 rows in one shot. My concern is that I have defined a specific index but yet MySql seems to be behaving as if the index is not defined.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Pagination via OFFSET*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) does not scale well.

Your 3-column index is as good as it can be.  But the processing still has to step over 55K rows (of the index BTree) before finding the 100 that you want.  (Cardinality does *not* matter.)

Or... Perhaps a search engine is crawling your site?  (I've had this problem.  The crawlers brought the web site to its knees.)

Or... Why the heck do you have 55K items in one set, and why the heck might anyone want to page through 550 pages to get to this 100?  That is, rethink the UI if you have thousands of items and the primary way to get to them is via pagination, not search or some other technique.

**BUG**

There is a serious problem with the query.  The query has no `ORDER BY`, so the Optimizer is free to deliver rows in different order for different `OFFSETs` (etc).  For example, with `OFFSET 0` it might deliver the first 100 rows in the table, ignoring the index; then for second 'page' it might use the index, thereby duplicating and/or skipping rows from page 1.

Add an `ORDER BY` with the same 3 columns, in the *same* order as in the `INDEX`.  (The order in the `WHERE` does not matter.)  This recommendation does not impact the performance question.

**Blow out cache**

1GB of RAM implies maybe 200M for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, which implies that at (perhaps) `OFFSET 55000`, the cache (buffer pool) will be blown out, and *all* queries will become I/O bound (until the cache can re-establish itself).  Beware of huge queries (such as this one) that need to touch more data (or index) than can fit in cache.

Comment: Rick, thanks for the link to Pagination Via Offset. I resolved the issue making use of the technique in that post. Added an order By id and an extra WHERE id > condition, This made the query run smoothly without the overhead that I had with my initial approach.. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

If You check used indexes, You can see - PL_ProductCategoryId have cardinality 17, it mean it has +- 17 possible values for all table rows.

It is very close to full-scan, client_id included in 2 indexes, both time as second part.

You can change index PL_SkuName_ClientId - just swap them (client_id, sky_id),

or create new index for client_id only.

Comment: That's my concern as well that the Cardinality is too low for the following query 

    SELECT * FROM `product_listings` WHERE `product_category_id` = 303 AND `client_id` = 39 AND `is_mapped` = '1' LIMIT 55000, 100;
 
Is there a way to work around this. Basically, a single client has close to 600,000 products whereas other clients have much lesser on average.

I don't know if there is a way to speed up this query, what are my options basically.

Comment: could You add my.ini config file and size of database? I miss this moment - You have only 1Gb of memory and it used not all

Comment: The best index has all 3 columns in it.  Any shorter index will have to read more rows.